# DotNetNuke Module does not show on page, steps to trouble shoot?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke Module created in DNN 4.9.2. It runs fine on my dev machine but when I post it to the live server, I just get a blank screen, well my skin with no content.

I have installed and then uninstalled, then reinstalled the module, same issue.

I must be overlooking something. Can anyone outline some ideas on how to trouble shoot this issue. I have done the following:

- Check code - exact match
- Check DNN Event Log - clean
- Look for errors - none
- Restart Site - same issue
- Check Windows Logs - clean
- Bang Head against desk - same issue, although now I have a headache

Any other ideas would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a bug in my code. The reason I didn't see an error was because that an xslt file path was wrong and it didn't kick in my `try catch`. I corrected the path and violà.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "Mode" selection at the top of the control panel isn't on Layout.

Are you running as an administrator?  Otherwise, do you know that the user has rights to see the module?

Comment: I tried to even log out and still nothing. I have deployed many modules and this is the first I have had work on my dev, and not on deployment, without any errors or nothing. 

I am host

Comment: and yes I played with the "Mode" to no avail, works fine in dev